# unexpected token: 'for' at line 6 column 6

Tags: trigger

I am new to the world of triggers.I have a custom object `customer` and if some condition is satisfied, i would like to insert fields from `customer` to `accounts`. how do i do that?i did the following but it says

> Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'for' at line 6 column 6 :

```
trigger CustomerTrigger on Customer__c (before insert) {

List<Account> acct = new List<Account>
//Trigger.new Represents a list of Customer records you are trying to insert.
//So iterate the list in a for loop     
      for (Customer__c newCustomerRecord: Trigger.new) {  

            //Check if the Customer belongs to a Key Account
            if(newCustomerRecord.Key_Account__c){

            acct.add(new Account(
                                    Customer_Name_c = newCustomerRecord.Customer_Name_c,
                                    Customer_Address_c = newCustomerRecord.Customer_Address_c));

            }
      }  

insert acct;
}
```

Comment: Custom object or field suffixes always have a double underscore i.e. __c rather than _c so check that.

Answer (score 2):

Please change :

```
List<Account> acct = new List<Account>
```

to

```
List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
```

Comment: Thankyou Artur Kępczyński. I have changed. but now it shows the following error: Error: Compile Error: Invalid field Customer_Name_c for SObject Account at line 12 column 55

Comment: the best place that you could start with is the platform documentation which have lot of examples will give you an idea of syntax, semantics and their usage...

Comment: I am always happy to help but you need also try harder by yourself - this comunicat means that there is no such field on object account, please check that. Also when you creating record you have to put all required fields

Comment: Thankyou, which is that one document which has clearly mentioned abt syntacs and semantics?can you post the link?

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you to understand how programming works:

Apex is similar to **Java (a programming language from oracle)**. Each instruction should be closed by a semicolon. `;`. In order to call a method use brackets `()` inside of these you can send parameters to your method.

The issue in your case was caused by missing brackets and semicolon.

```
List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
```

`List<Account>` indicates that you want to declare a variable. You variable is called `accts`. The variable is initialized (`=`) by a method called `new List<Account>()`. It creates a new object from type List.

In order to learn more about basic programming concepts please visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger CustomerTrigger on Customer__c (before insert){
    List<Account> accts = new List<Account>();
         for (Customer__c newCustomerRecord: Trigger.new) {  
            //Check if the Customer belongs to a Key Account
            if(newCustomerRecord.Key_Account__c!=Null)
            {
                Account ac=new Account();
                ac.Name= newCustomerRecord.Name;
                ac.BillingStreet= newCustomerRecord.Customer_Street__c;
                ac.BillingCity=newCustomerRecord.Customer_City__c;
                ac.BillingCountry=newCustomerRecord.Customer_Country__c;
                accts.add(ac);
            }
      }  
    insert accts;
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to explain *why* this code will help. What did you change?

Comment: To add to @AdrianLarson comments, are you aware you've answered a 2 year old question that already has an answer that although not accepted, explains the problem with the code posted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

First of all,
I think you have not noticed that there is no such field on account object like **Customer_Name_c** and **Customer_Address_c** (that’s why this error occurred “Invalid field Customer_Name_c for SObject Account “). So you have to create these custom field in Account to map with customer object or you should use standard fields of account object.
And one other point that you can’t map address field directly. So you should use these account fields(BillingCity,BillingStreet).